# AWS Lambda Error (tesseract not installed)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tesseract

I have an issue about tesseract on my aws lambda. tesseract is working locally but not when i run the equivalent code in the lambda. The lambda works on python 3.7, tesseract is 0.3.7 (arn : arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pytesseract:17).

I've installed the layers of tesseract and pillow.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('hello_world.png'), config=custom_config)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'Image'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: where you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at this repository, which provides a blank sample app for Python: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-python

It provides a step-by-step guide on how to configure and deploy a Python Lambda function with external dependencies.

Best,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

`Image.open('hello_world.png')` is from `Pillow` probably, so you need `Pillow` as well. Luckilly there is a [public layer](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/deployments/python3.8/arns/eu-west-3.csv) with it already:

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-Pillow:10
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it but the pillow layer was already on the lambda..